# Script error python chromedriver selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

im a begginer and i have a problem with my script

I show you a screenshot and I have highlighted the steps I want to do and circled the error logs, if someone can help me please I really don't have the solution even if it may seem stupid for them others..

[SCRIPT IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zDuca.png)

Comment: Please post your code as text inside your question.

Answer (score 0):

You don't import webdriver at all in your code. Try adding it at the beginning:

```
from selenium import webdriver
```

What is more, you are trying to sendKeys or click on non-existing elements, you need to assign find_element to variables, which you are referencing further.